# div backgrounds not working correctly with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, background

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div id="view-hole"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <p>here is sometext</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div id="mebg" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
                    <script>$('body').stellar();</script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is **css**

```
#mebg{
     height:400px;
     background-image: url("http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
     background-size: cover;

 }
```

Here is my result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5OAa.jpg or codepen https://codepen.io/mikelennon92/project/editor/ArNdjw/

if i make the background a flat color, say background: red;

It spans across all 6 columns and works normally.

Comment: Can you confirm that MEBG{} is used as ID in your CSS ?

Comment: I can, i just removed the <script> tag from underneath and it seems to work normally. This must be an issue with that and not the bootstrap framework :/

Comment: if i make the background a flat color, say background: red, if you are trging to give in hexdecimal value, add #

Answer (score 0):

check out the snippet below, hopefully this one will stand for you. Good luck!

```css
#mebg {
 height:400px;
 background-image: url("http://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-tutorials-hero-00e10b1f.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: top left;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div id="view-hole"></div>
                    <p>here is sometext</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div id="mebg" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
                        <p>Check this one out!</p>
                        <script>$('body').stellar();</script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```